# Python script to get username and password from text?

Tags: python

I have a script for creating accounts that outputs the following:

```
creating user in XYZ: username: testing firstName: Bob lastName:Test email:auto999@nowhere.com password:gWY6*Pja&4
```

So, I need to create a python script that will store the username and password in a csv file.

I tried splitting this string by spaces and colons then indexing it, but this isn't working quite properly and could fail if the message is different. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: use regex, probably

Answer (score 0):

Regex is almost always the answer to this type of issue:

```
import re

text = 'creating user in XYZ: username: testing firstName: Bob lastName:Test email:auto999@nowhere.com password:gWY6*Pja&4'

pattern = '.*username:\s*(\S+)\s*firstName:\s*(\S+)\s*lastName:\s*(\S+)\s*email:\s*(\S+)\s*password:\s*(\S+)'

values = re.findall(pattern, text)

print(values)
```

Output:

```
[('testing', 'Bob', 'Test', 'auto999@nowhere.com', 'gWY6*Pja&4')]
```

[Regexr Pattern Explanation](https://regexr.com/72l6s)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for *Regex* here, a simple but robust parsing is enough:

```
def get_data(account: str, attribute: str) -> str:
    data = ' '.join(account.split()).strip()
    for k, v in {' :': ':', ' : ': ':', ': ': ':'}.items():
        data = data.replace(k, v)
    index1 = data.find(attribute)
    index2 = data.find(' ', index1)
    return data[index1 + len(attribute + ':'): len(account) if index2 == -1 else index2]
```

example of use:

```
acc = "username: testing firstName: Bob lastName:Test email:auto999@nowhere.com password:gWY6*Pja&4"
print(get_data(acc, 'username'))
print(get_data(acc, 'password'))
```

output:

```
testing
gWY6*Pja&4
```

As the generator is yours, you can control how the accounts are created and I personally think that *Regex* is not easy to maintain.
This approach works even adding extra spaces or changing the order of the attributes, e.g.:

```
acc = "  username:  testing firstName: Bob    lastName :Test email:auto999@nowhere.com password   :   gWY6*Pja&4 "
acc =  "firstName: Bob username: testing email:auto999@nowhere.com password:gWY6*Pja&4 lastName:Test "
```